# Print next to a text a picture or char(251) in report builder

Tags: delphi

I draw a checkmark next to the some text in a Devexpress datagrid column, now I have to print it. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your printing engine. Usually you can hook an event in order to do your custom drawing (for example if you use DevExpress's Printing System's `TdxComponentPrinter` then you have `OnCustomDrawPage`).

With other printing engines you have a more fine grained events (one per printed object). You can add your 'checkbox' by using a special font and a special character (eg. *Wingdings* - 0xFC or 0xFE) or even a special object for this if your reporting engine has one (for ex. **FastReport** has one).

OTOH, why don't you use a separate column for your checkmark? Anyway is a separate bit of information and normally it should reside in a separate column. And then, usually, the reporting engines will handle it much more easily.

HTH

**UPDATE**: I saw that you use ReportBuilder. I don't have experience with ReportBuilder but the above principles should (still) apply.